# array_column() expects at most 3 parameters, 13 given

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a `PHP` array as follows:

`print_r($myarray);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
         (
            [JAN] => 484603732
            [FEB] => 350203732
            [MAR] => 133347732
            [APR] => 203347732
            [MEI] => 79797732
            [JUNI] => 112047732
            [JULI] => 380597732
            [AGS] => 76597732
            [SEP] => 86597732
            [OKT] => 120397732
            [NOV] => 391597732
            [DES] => 58597732
         )

)
```

I want to delete element like `[JAN], [FEB], [MAR], ...`

But I little bit confused about how to handle it with `array_column`

So far, I've tried:

```
$array = array_column($myarray, 'JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MEI','JUNI','JULI','AGS','SEP','OKT','NOV','DES');
```

But, still facing error

> array_column() expects at most 3 parameters, 13 given

My expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 484603732
    [1] => 350203732
    [2] => 133347732
    [3] => 203347732
    [4] => 79797732
    [5] => 112047732
    [6] => 380597732
    [7] => 76597732
    [8] => 86597732
    [9] => 120397732
    [10] => 391597732
    [11] => 58597732
)
```

Any well thought to advise will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `array_column()` here. According to PHP documentation

> [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key. Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array.

You can simply use [**array_values()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to remove all the keys.

```
$array = array_values($myarray[0])
```